# Using a ; or && with $@

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to do something with a cron wrapper and my cron looks something like

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/wrapper cd /tmp/ && ls
```

Then wrapper looks like

```
#!/bin/bash 

"$@"
```

When I run it I can't get the semi colon or && to work as I'm hoping.

```
[root@domain.net ~/test]# pwd
/root/test
[root@domain.net ~/test]# ls
test.sh
[root@domain.net ~/test]# ./test.sh cd /tmp && ls
test.sh
```

So in that case it goes into tmp then the weapper script exits.. and it runs ls in my cwd.

If I add '' around the command I get

```
[root@domain.net ~/test]# ./test.sh 'cd /tmp && ls'
./test.sh: line 3: cd /tmp && ls: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing with the "$@" it is trying to add in the single quote to the command being run

I support I can strip out the single quotes before the "$@" but I was hoping not to do that.. any tips or is this even solvable in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/usr/bin/wrapper cd /tmp/ && ls` gets parsed as `(/usr/bin/wrapper cd /tmp/) && ls`. Even if you do manage to pass the arguments to `wrapper` properly, it doesn't understand them; `&&` is a shell construct. I'm not sure exactly what you were aiming for with this wrapper script, but I suspect you can just replace it with `bash -c`, which takes a string and tells bash to evaluate it as though you'd typed it directly into the shell:

```
* * * * * root bash -c "cd /tmp/ && ls"
```